# gecode search google withe wunderground

Tags: jquery

my code weather wunderground all most done . i want search please via google gecode , and he work . but the problem is when i put `address` in  `url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/8dee7a0127c63e7f/forecast/conditions/lang:AR/q/"+address+".json",` get error withe

```
funcation Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp_c' of undefined
```

code

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(weather) {

 $.ajax({
 url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/8dee7a0127c63e7f/forecast/conditions/lang:AR/q/"+address+".json",
 dataType : "jsonp",

 success : function(data) {

        var tempCelsius = Math.round(data.current_observation.temp_c);
                if (tempCelsius < 15){
                    $("#temp").css("color", "#00DFF9");
                } else if (tempCelsius < 20){
                    $("#temp").css("color", "#21DBE1");
                } else if (tempCelsius < 25) {
                    $("#temp").css("color", "#A0FF74");
                } else if (tempCelsius < 30) {
                    $("#temp").css("color", "##FEB900");
                } else if (tempCelsius < 35) {
                    $("#temp").css("color", "##FE7400");
                } else if (tempCelsius < 40) {
                    $("#temp").css("color", "#FE5100");
                } else if (tempCelsius > 45) {
                    $("#temp").css("color", "#FE0000");
                } else if (tempCelsius > 50) {
                    $("#temp").css("color", "##FE0000");
                } else if (tempCelsius > 55) {
                    $("#temp").css("color", "#E8250C");
                }


                $("#temp").html(Math.round(tempCelsius )+ "&#176;C");
                $("#icon").html('<img src="'+data.current_observation.icon_url+'" class="center-block">');


 var html = '';
   html += '<h3 class="text-center">'+data.current_observation.weather+'</h3>';

  html += '<h5 class="text-center">'+data.location.city+'</h5>';

   $("#deatils").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");
 //next hour ..'
            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var weatherData = data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[i];

             var html = '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><p id="celsius" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">العليا ' + weatherData.high.celsius + '&deg;C ,<br> ' + weatherData.low.celsius + '&deg;C صغرى </p></div>';

html += '<div class="ui-block-b"><p class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">'+ weatherData.date.weekday + ' ' + weatherData.date.day+ ' </p><br></div>';

   $("#nexthour").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");


            }


    //next days ..'

 var html = '';


    html += '</div>';

  $("#days").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");


 }
 });
 });//add this code. Need to close the 'jQuery(document)'
```

Answer (score 0):

That means `temp_c` property doesn't exist for one or more node.

Eg.

```
var json = {};
json.current_observation = {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"New York, NY",
        "city":"New York",
        "state":"NY",
        "state_name":"New York",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "zip":"10001",
        "magic":"3",
        "wmo":"99999",
        "latitude":"40.75013351",
        "longitude":"-73.99700928",
        "elevation":"17.00000000"
        },
        "temp_f":69.1,
        "temp_c":20.6,
        "relative_humidity":"95%",
        "wind_string":"Calm",
        "wind_dir":"جنوب",
        "wind_degrees":171,
        "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KNYNEWYO395",
        "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=40.746910,-73.992836",
        "nowcast":""
    }
```

In order to check whether a key/field/property exist or not, You may use **[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)** method.

```
json.current_observation.hasOwnProperty("temp_c"); //returns true
json.current_observation.hasOwnProperty("imaginary"); //returns false
```